# elixir digesting a httpotion response

Tags: elixir

I did a HTTPotion and received a response similar to this.

```
"{\"total\": 1564, \"businesses\": [{\"review_count\": 139}, {\"review_count\": 154}]}"
```

What type is this data? How do I get access to the first review_count?

Answer (score 3):

This is json data.You can use [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison) to decode it

```
iex()> response = "{\"total\": 1564, \"businesses\": [{\"review_count\": 139}, {\"review_count\": 154}]}"
"{\"total\": 1564, \"businesses\": [{\"review_count\": 139}, {\"review_count\": 154}]}"

iex()> response |> Poison.decode! |> Map.get("businesses") |> List.first |> Map.get("review_count")
139
```

or a shorter way:

```
iex()> response |> Poison.decode! |> get_in(["businesses", Access.at(0), "review_count"])
139
```